# Communication servlet to jsp without client request

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm working on a project where we use Tomcat 8 as a application server and hence JSP and Servlets. Each JSP displays a kind of project list. The user of the application has the possibilty to simulate a project. What this means is not that important. When the user clicks the 'simulate'-button, the following process will be performed:

1. Via Ajax (javascript) a servlet will be executed which produces a zip file and stores the file on the hard disk of the server
2. a 'simulation'-flag will be set in the database for the respective project
3. a external java program (at the backend) listens for the 'simulation'-flag and if a flag for a project is set, the external program grabs the zip file stored by the web application
4. the external java program then runs the simulation for this project.
5. when the simulation is done, the external java program stores a new zip file on the hard disk of the server, sets a 'hey, I'm ready'-flag in the database and calls a servlet of the web application
6. this servlet saves the information of the data in the new zip file to the database
7. finish

So my question is: What is the best way to inform the JSP that the simulation is done?
The JSP still displays that the project is in simulation progress. My current idea is the following:

I could periodically send a Ajax request to the server to check the database for the 'hey I'm ready'-flag and if it is set, I could display the result on the JSP. But I've got the feeling that there are smarter solutions.

Maybe I could use the last servlet call (see point 5) to somehow inform the JSP that the simulation is done? The problem is that this servlet is not called by the client but by the external java program.

Do you have any suggestions? Or is there any technology I should read about?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

using asynchronous ajax calls means that the function will return when the servlet finishes it's job and returns some HTTP code (200 for success).

so this example:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: Config.serverUrl+'/simulationServlet',
                    type: 'GET',

                    success: function(result) {
                           $('#infoBox').text("simulation is over");
                       }
                });
```

will show that the simulation is done.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is that I have two servlet calls. The first at step 2. The second and step 5. The first servlet is called by the client who uses the web application. The first servlet just sets a flag in the database and returns a "success" to the client. But the second servlet is called by the external java program (which resides on the server). I have to somehow know when the second servlet is done.

Comment: this should be a chained call because the application logic is not OK. think of it this way. since you want a job done, you need to hit a servlet and let it do whatever it wants and return when the job finishes. let's call it a Facade for example. The servlet can call other servlets etc etc. 
There is another programming pattern publish/subscribe that you can use but you need to set up a lot of stuff to push notifications to the client application.